# How to work with $stdout

Tags: ruby

```
filename = "#{k}""/kabab" 
extension = ".txt" 

for i in 1..10 
  $stdout=File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w')
  puts "sachin"
end

puts "amit"
```

whats my problem is in last file  means kabab10.txt i geeting the output like sachin and amit
but i don't want amit to be come in 10th file how to solve it`

Comment: don't change global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change `$stdout`, and certainly not without storing away the old value somewhere so you can restore it after you're done with it.

Instead, call `puts` on the file object:

```
File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w') do |file|
  10.times do
    file.puts "sachin" # This goes to the file
  end
end

puts "amit" # This goes to standard output
```

Comment: thanks lars ...but lars
File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w') do |file| 
  10.times do 
    run
  end 
end 




run body in some other file
def run
puts "sachin"
now how to do that when i called run as file.run then i have a error like private methos run called for file like that 
puts "amit

Comment: @amit: Send `file` as an argument to your `run` method, and in the run method do `file.puts "amit"`

Comment: yaa i did same i would like to know the reason for this error

Comment: i also sent file as an argument but just i want to know what is private method run called for file

Comment: The File class has an instance method called `run` that is private, meaning it can not be called with an explicit receiver. See for example: http://blog.zerosum.org/2007/11/22/ruby-method-visibility

Comment: lars what is this explicit receiver

Comment: Follow the link I included in my previous comment, and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `puts` to put sachin to the files.

```
$f = File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w')
$f.puts "sachin"
```

Comment: @amit tomar: If you never reassign stdout, and you call "puts amit", "amit" will be printed to the console.  Not to a file.  Just run the program with "ruby foo.rb".  No pipes or anything.

Comment: Why use a global variable at all?

Answer (score 0):

i edit your question but i don't think how you get amit in all your files as you using it out of the loop.But i hope following helps you if you put `puts "amit"` in `for loop`

```
puts "amit" if i != 10
```

Edited :- Do you like something like following

```
filename = "kabab" 
extension = ".txt" 

puts "amit"

for i in 1..10 
  $stdout=File.open("#{filename}#{i}#{extension}" ,'w')
    puts "sachin"

end
```

Comment: no salil i m getting amit in last file means in 10th file o dont want this