# how to solve this I/O error in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
require 'fileutils.rb'

k=FileUtils.mkdir_p "d:/pptomasdsdr1xks_6b27"

filename = "#{k}""/kddabab"  
extension = ".txt"  
 co=1

  $stdout=File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w') 

puts "sachin" 

$stdout.close

puts "amit"
```

im getting error like

stdout.rb:14:in `write': closed stream (IOError)
    from stdout.rb:14:in`puts'

i don't want amit to be printd in my file so that i close the file but i got this error
help me plzzz

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218028/how-to-work-with-stdout-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$stdout` to write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change `$stdout`, and certainly not without storing away the old value somewhere so you can restore it after you're done with it.

Instead, call `puts` on the file object:

```
File.open("#{filename}#{co}#{extension}" ,'w') do |file|
  file.puts "sachin" # This goes to the file
end

puts "amit" # This goes to standard output
```

Comment: but lars can i call any function using file object